# Simple list manipulation in Python

Tags: python

From the given two lists:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'mango', 'avocardo']
quantities = [5, 8, 7, 15, 22]
```

How to get the result below?

```
fruits_having_less_than_10quantities = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']
```

I am looking for implementing it using dictionary.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It's not a dictionary-type problem.

Comment: What do you get when you cross Ricky Ricardo with an avocado?  Avocardo!  (This was a light-hearted attempt to humorously point out your spelling mistake)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'mango', 'avocardo']
quantities = [5, 8, 7, 15, 22]

fhlt = [fruit for fruit,num in zip(fruits,quantities) if num < 10]
    # => ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']
```

**Edit** or as a dictionary:

```
fruitnum = {fruit:num for fruit,num in zip(fruits, quantities) if num < 10}
    # => {'apple': 5, 'banana': 8, 'kiwi': 7}
```

**Edit2:** if you are concerned about extra temporary lists, in Python 2, you can

```
from itertools import izip
fhlt = [fruit for fruit,num in izip(fruits,quantities) if num < 10]
```

instead; in Python 3 this is not necessary, as `zip` is already a generator.

Answer (score 2):

I really think you should use a dictionary {fruit: quantity} but here you are

```
>>> fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'mango', 'avocardo']
>>> quantities = [5, 8, 7, 15, 22]
>>> fruits_having_less_than_10quantities = [ elem[0] for elem in zip(fruits, quantities) if elem[1] < 10 ]
>>> fruits_having_less_than_10quantities
['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
[fruits[i] for i in xrange(0, len(fruits)) if quantities[i] < 10]
```

The above has the advantage that it doesn't create any extra temporary lists. As others have pointed out, this is not a dictionary-type problem, but still…

Answer (score 0):

**I think we can trying using bisect:**

```
from bisect import bisect

def disect(fr, qr, n, side=None):
    ind = bisect(zip(*sorted(zip(fr, qr), key=lambda tup: tup[1]))[1], n)
    if side == 'left':
        return fr[:ind]
    elif side == 'right':
        return fr[ind:]
    raise Exception("which side you want")

fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'mango', 'avocardo']
quantities = [5, 8, 7, 15, 22]

print disect(fruits, quantities, 10, 'left')
print disect(fruits, quantities, 10, 'right')
```